# Positive zeroes of a quadratic form

Tags: polynomials, matrix-equations, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

Let $M$ be a real symmetric (non-zero) matrix. Consider the quadratic form,
\begin{eqnarray}
Q(\vec{t})&\equiv&\vec{t}^{\,T} M \,\vec{t} \\
&=& 
\begin{pmatrix}
t_0 ~ \ldots ~ t_N
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
M_{00} & \ldots & M_{0N} \\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
M_{N0} & \ldots & M_{NN}  
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
t_0 \\ \vdots \\ t_N
\end{pmatrix} \;,
\end{eqnarray}
where the $t_i$ are all real. My question is as follows.

> Is it possible to determine necessary and sufficient conditions on $M$ for there to exist a solution $\vec{t}$ to the equation
>   $$
> Q(\vec{t})=0\,,
> $$
>   for which $t_i>0 ~\,\forall i\,$?

In particular I am interested in the case where $M_{i,j} \in \mathbb{Z}$, though this may not be a simplification.

If it is not possible to give complete necessary and sufficient conditions, I would also be interested in sufficient conditions and strong necessary conditions. For example, clearly a necessary condition is that $M$ have elements of opposite sign, and a sufficient condition is that $M$ have diagonal elements of opposite sign. (I have some slightly tighter conditions, but I am wondering if there are significantly stronger conditions.)

Comment: Did you try the case when $M$ is diagonal?

Comment: The case with $M$ diagonal is trivial. Hence you might say that I should transform to the eigenbasis of $M$. However it then becomes difficult to see the condition $t_i > 0 ~ \forall i$ (which holds in the original basis and not the eigenbasis). Incidentally, it is also clearly a necessary condition that the eigenvalues are not all of the same sign (though this would be true regardless of the condition on $\vec{t}$).